# Translate phone-number regex to java

Tags: java, regex

I found this regex in a plugin called hi5validator for jQuery, and I found it pretty good, I'm already using it on JavaScript:

```
/^([\+][0-9]{1,3}([ \.\-])?)?([\(][0-9]{1,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-]{1,32})(([A-Za-z \:]{1,11})?[0-9]{1,4}?)$/
```

I wanted to use this regex but in Java, and I tried to do this same thing with another regex in that library, but when I used an online evaluator, the expression gave lots of trouble. Fortunately, i found another regex that helped with that.

As for this one, can someone give me the proper Java version?

Comment: Give it a go. Come back to us.

Comment: I think the problem was with the backslashes ``\``, you need to use ``\\`` to get a simple backslash in a Java String. Also I am not sure about the first and last slash `/`, it is not needed.

Comment: `[\+]` is overcomplicating things. You don't need to escape `+` twice (once with ``\`` and once with `[..]`) to produce regex which will match `+` literal.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of your regex is fine - you need to fix some minor details:

- Put double quotes `"` instead of slashes `/` around your regex
- Do not escape with back slashes parentheses `(` `)`, dashes `-` in trailing positions, pluses `+`, colons `:`, and dots `.` inside character classes (I am not sure if it is necessary to escape these characters in Javascript either).

Here is what you should get:

```
"^([+][0-9]{1,3}([ .-])?)?([(][0-9]{1,6}[)])?([0-9 .-]{1,32})(([A-Za-z :]{1,11})?[0-9]{1,4}?)$"
```

Comment: Actually escaping `-` in character class is good idea. Only reason why OP can skip it here is that `-` is not creating range of characters since it is placed at the end of character class `[...-]`. Anyway +1.

Comment: I see. What I did was change the slashes for quotes, and escape every backslash (\\). The regex I put up there was the original from JavaScript. So I thought that in Java I should escape these backslashes. Is this correct? `"^([\\+][0-9]{1,3}([ \\.\\-])?)?([\\(][0-9]{1,6}[\\)])?([0-9 \\.\\-]{1,32})(([A-Za-z \\:]{1,11})?[0-9]{1,4}?)$"`

Comment: @Xanathos Yes, if you would like to keep the backslashes in the regular expression, you need to escape each one of them with a backslash.